# Powershell get row older than 30 days and export them into another csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file as per below format and i want to export row which is older then 30 days

```
Target;Date;Safe
Box11;01/10/20;abc_test1
Box2;02/10/20;xyz_test2
Box3;03/10/20;mnp_test3
Box2;01/09/20;xyz_test2
Box3;02/09/20;mnp_test3
Box11;03/09/20;abc_test1
```

**I use the script as below but failed**

```
$Data = Import-CSV "D:\Dev\test1.csv" | where { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date, "dd/MM/yy", $null) -lt (get-date).date.adddays(-30)}
$Data | Export-Csv "D:\Dev\test1234.csv"
```

**Failed reason -**

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not
> recognized as a valid DateTime.

**Expected result in a new csv file would be**

```
Box2;01/09/20;xyz_test2
Box3;02/09/20;mnp_test3
Box11;03/09/20;abc_test1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **-delimiter** on both import and export:

```
$Data = Import-CSV "D:\Dev\test1.csv" -delimiter ";" | where { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date, "dd/MM/yy", $null) -lt (get-date).date.adddays(-30)}
$Data | Export-Csv "D:\Dev\test1234.csv" -delimiter ";"
```

Comment: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:64
+ ... " | where { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date, "dd/MM/yy", $null) -lt (g ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException